# Weakest topology equivalence

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Prove the equivalence of the following

1. $Y \subset X$ has the subspace topology .
2. $Y$ has the weakest topology to make the inclusion $i:Y\to X$ continuous.
3. For all topological spaces $Z$ and maps $f:Z\to Y$ the map $f$ is continuous iff the map $F:Z\to X$ such that $F=( i\circ f)$  is continuous .

I did $1\implies2$ and $2\implies 3$. But I am not able to figure out which topological space should i take so that $Y$ has subspace topology that proves $3\implies 1$. Please just give hint.

Comment: Let $\tau$ denote the topology $Y$ has in 3., and $\sigma$ the subspace topology. For $Z$, use $(Y,\tau)$ and $(Y,\sigma)$.

Comment: yes, thank you i got it....

Comment: I see clearly $\tau \subset \sigma$ but how the other direction, i am confused, please

Comment: Well, $\operatorname{id} \colon (Y,\tau) \to (Y,\tau)$ is continuous. By 3., that means what?

Comment: this gives $\tau =\tau$ isn't it? yes i am confused right here, how does this bring the reverse relation with $\sigma$

Comment: It means $i\circ \operatorname{id} = i \colon (Y,\tau) \to X$ is continuous. And that means what?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to get reverse inclusion with $\sigma$. I have understood what you wrote but unable to get consequences...

Comment: What are the open sets in $\sigma$?

Comment: they are preimage of open set under inclusion map, right?

Comment: Exactly. And $i\colon (Y,\tau)\to X$ being continuous therefore means ...

Comment: Thank you, I got it, now it gives that inclusion, wow..

Answer (score 1):

Consider the identity-mapping on Y. The identity is always continuous, which you may translate into something else by part 3.

Comment: Identity is not continuous always when space is under different topology, but here it is true because of assumption 3